# How to get url after a get request in jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
function getLongUrl(domReference, url, callback){

  $.get(url, function(data){
    console.log(url);
  });
}
```

A get request to any short url, should always yield its actual endpoint. how do I get the endpoint of a url by doing a get request to it in Jquery?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie The aim of the exercise is to get the long url from short urls.

Comment: Can you elaborate your Q. It's bit confusing what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Apologies about the confusion. The idea is to extract the long url out of a short url, the one that has been shortened by a url shortener. In Python, if I do a r = requests.get(url), then r.url contains the long url, as that's the destination of the short url.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie It would help me to figure out where a shortened URL like a bit.ly one is being actually directed to. That's the use of it.

Comment: Your first problem is that Ajax does not handle HTTP redirects. That means either **a)** the source URL will be unchanged and the data is redirected or **b)** you have to handle the redirect yourself to get the real data. Suggest you use Fiddler2 (or another network tool) first and see if what you want is actually in the response header.